# How to create a shortcut or batch file to kill a process

Tags: batch-file, shortcut, taskmanager, taskkill

I would like to create a shortcut or batch file to kill a process `NorisWin32.exe` in two clicks instead of repeatedly killing it in Task Manager.

Comment: What did you try? Anything went wrong?

Comment: Try `taskkill /?`.

Comment: easy with one click, but I'm still struggling, adding a second click somehow.

Comment: @Stephan What if you put it inside a folder?

Comment: @Frederik.L good idea. Or we declare a double-click to be two clicks `:D`

Comment: A double-click is two clicks! _the clue is in the word double._

Comment: @melpomene You're right. I have used a shortcut with 'taskkill.exe /IM NorisWin32.exe /F'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the location you want the shortcut:

- **Right-Click** , and choose **New → Shortcut**.
- In the input box choose and **paste** any **`1`** of the following command strings:

  ```dos
  Powershell (GPs NorisWin32).Kill()
  ```

  ```dos
  WMIC Process Where "Name='NorisWin32.exe'" Call Terminate
  ```

  ```dos
  TaskKill /IM NorisWin32.exe
  ```
- Click **Next**.
- Enter a name in the input box, *e.g. **Kill Noris***.
- Select **Finish**.
- **Double-Click** the new shortcut as necessary.

Comment: Hey Compo, can I create this shortcut with two commands?
Kill process then restart?

I have an app that links my label printer to a courier label purchasing website and by their own confession the app is designed poorly where the connection is lost if windows goes to sleep.
I am needing to kill the process and relaunch the app daily. Painful.

Comment: You could @Beno, however for the first you'd need to run multiple powershell commands, in the format ```powershell -nop -c "your commands here with semicolon seperators and nested doublequotes escaped"```; for the latter two, you'd need to use ```cmd /d /c "your commands here with ampersand seperators"```. I'm not however going to offer full code, as this is technically a new question.